# Just another jquery newbie, passing and receive params

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  InitFirstImage(imageId);
</script>

<img id="1" class="details" width="50" height="50" src="....">
<img id="2" class="details" width="50" height="50" src="....">
...
<img id="99" class="details" width="50" height="50" src="....">
```

I need to know first img id(this numbers will be generated dynamicly and it will be stored in collection), so I need to know that Id and pass that value to InitFirstImage() js.

Second question
How can I in js receive that imageId and use that value for some operation, alert for example, on calling script, not onclick event.

**Update:**
Now when I have first img Id how can I use it for clone() function.

```
var clone = $(this).clone();
```

Can I use this for something like

```
var firstImageId = $("img.details").first().attr("id");
var clone = $(firstImageId).clone(); //this doesn't work.
```

Thank you all.

Comment: According to the HTML specification, IDs cannot be numbers or start with numbers. Beware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var firstImageId=$("img.details").first().attr("id");
```

and make sure you call the InitFirstImage method in the document ready

```
$(function(){

  var firstImageId=$("img.details").first().attr("id");
   InitFirstImage(firstImageId);
});
```

Here is the sample : http://jsfiddle.net/2M2Dp/1/

**UPDATE :** Since the OP updated his question to do a clone of the first image

To get a clone of first image, use the `clone()` method. The below example creates a clone of the first image with "details" class and then append to a div with id "cloneArea"

```
var imageObject=$("img.details").first();
imageObject.clone().appendTo($("#cloneArea"));
```

Here is the working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/2M2Dp/10/

`clone` method documentation : http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: @user313378 : Why you want clone an image Id ? i guess you want to clone the image object itself

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
var firstImgId = $("img:first").attr("id");
```

2)

```
alert( firstImgId );

myFunc( firstImgId );
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the id of the first img tag:

```
var imgId = $("img:first").attr("id");  //first image in the document
var imgId = $("img.details:first").attr("id");  //first image with details class
```

imgId now has the id string.  To pass the id to InitFirstImage():

```
InitFirstImage(imgId);
```

You can do other things with it too, as it's just a variable:

```
alert(imgId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it be simpler for InitFirstImage to to get the first img tag with the class details ?

Eg:

```
$("img.details").first();
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To get the first img id you can do this : 
                $('img').first().attr('id')